# cannot align css in php echo - jquery is not working

Tags: php, jquery, css

here is the link of the code

http://snipsave.com/user/profile/karthikeyan#5352

the problem is when tha button view is clicked it fetches data from sql and displays it. it workz fine .. but when the button is aligned using CSS its not working ...

i just need the button to be on right side .. when clicked view .. it should show the detail one next line leaving a gab in between a title and content ...

can any1 help ??

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Should be text-align
Try this replacing your original code

```
while($data = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
    echo("<div class=\"pos_t\">$data[1]<button style=\"text-align:right;\" class=\"show\">View</button><i style=\"display:none;\">$data[2]</i></div><br>");
}
```

Comment: its not working .. the button get stick together with the data[1].